# Why can't I have two submit buttons serving different functions?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="scripts/apply.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jobs.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/enhancements.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SwinTech</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body class="applypage">
    <header>
      <div class="main">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
          </li>
          <li class="active">
            <a href="apply.html">Apply</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a href="enhancements2.html">Enhancements</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
  <section class="applything">
<h2> Warning: you have 3 minutes to fill out the form before being redirected back to previous page </h2>
<br>
    <h2>Job application:</h2>
    <br>
    <div class="containerr">
      <form action="https://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php" method="post" id="regform">
        <p>Your Name: <span id="job1"></span></p>
        
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." required="required" maxlength="25" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) || (event.charCode==32)">


        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." required="required" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) || (event.charCode==32)">

   <label for="start">Date of birth:</label>
    <input type="date" id="start" required="required" name="date of birth" value="2021-10-04" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="gender"> Select you gender</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <select name="gender" id="gender" required="required">
          <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
          <option value="male">Male</option>
          <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="streetname">Street Address</label>
        <input type="text" id="streetname" name="streetname" required="required" placeholder="Your street name..." maxlength="40" />
        <label for="suburb">Suburb/Town</label>
        <input type="text" id="suburb" name="suburb" required="required" placeholder="Your suburb/town..." maxlength="40">
        <label for="state">Choose a state:</label>
        <br>
        <select name="state" id="state" required="required">
          <option value="">Please Select</option>
          <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
          <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
          <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
          <option value="NT">NT</option>
          <option value="WA">WA</option>
          <option value="SA">SA</option>
          <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
          <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
        <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" required="required" placeholder="Your postcode..." maxlength="4" minlength="4" pattern="^[0-9]{4}$">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="emailadd" placeholder="Your email address.." required="required">
        <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phonenumb" placeholder="e.g. 0451124561" minlength="8" maxlength="12" required="required">
        <br>
        <label>Skills</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill1" value="Javascript">
        <label for="skill1"> Extensive knowledge of Javascript</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill2" value="Python">
        <label for="skill2"> Extensive knowledge of Python</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill3" value="Networking">
        <label for="skill3"> Extensive knowledge of Networking</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill4" value="Data Storage">
        <label for="skill4"> Extensive knowledge of Data storage fundamentals</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill5" value="Security Foundations">
        <label for="skill5"> Extensive knowledge of Security foundations</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill6" value="AWS Service Selection">
        <label for="skill6"> Extensive knowledge of AWS service selection</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill7" value="Teamwork">
        <label for="skill7"> Ability to work in a team</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill8" value="5+ Years">
        <label for="skill8"> 5+ years experience</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill9" value="10+ Years">
        <label for="skill9"> 10+ years experience</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill10" value="20+ Years">
        <label for="skill10"> 20+ years experience</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input
    type="checkbox"
    id="other"
    name="other"
    value="other"
    onclick="otherCheckBox()"
  />
        <label for="other"> I have other skills. Please list other skills below.</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
        <textarea id="otherbox" name="other skill" placeholder="textarea" style="height:200px"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="Apply">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="cancelpurchase" value="Cancel Application"></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-content"></div>
    <div class="footer-bottom"></div> &copy; swintech.com | Designed by Bilal El-leissy
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
"use strict"

function otherCheckBox() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("other");  //Getting the 'other' CheckBox
    var otherBox = document.getElementById("otherbox");  //Getting the TextBox
    if (checkBox.checked) {
      otherBox.required = "true"; //Setting the 'required' parameter to true if checkbox is checked
    } else {
      otherBox.required = "";  //Setting the 'required' parameter to false if the checkbox is not checked
    }
  }


function validate() {
  var errMsg = "";
  var result = true;

var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
var skill = document.getElementById("skill").value;
var other = document.getElementById("other").value;
var otherbox = document.getElementById("otherbox").value;

  var postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
  var state = document.getElementById("state").options[
document.getElementById("state").selectedIndex
  ].text;

  var regex;
  //VIC = 3 OR 8, NSW = 1 OR 2 ,QLD = 4 OR 9 ,NT = 0 ,WA = 6 ,SA=5 ,TAS=7 ,ACT= 0.
  switch (state) {
case "Please Select":
  return false;
case "VIC":
  regex = new RegExp(/(3|8)\d+/);
  break;
case "NSW":
  regex = new RegExp(/(1|2)\d+/);
  break;
case "QLD":
  regex = new RegExp(/(4|9)\d+/);
  break;
case "NT":
  regex = new RegExp(/0\d+/);
  break;
case "WA":
  regex = new RegExp(/6\d+/);
  break;
case "SA":
  regex = new RegExp(/5\d+/);
  break;
case "TAS":
  regex = new RegExp(/7\d+/);
  break;
case "ACT":
  regex = new RegExp(/0\d+/);
  break;
  }
  if (!postcode.match(regex)) {
errMsg = errMsg + "State and postcode do not match\n";
result = false;
  }

  if (errMsg) {
alert(errMsg);
  }

  if (result) {
storeBooking(
  fname,
  lname,
  start,
  email,
  gender,
  phone,
  streetname,
  suburb,
  state,
  postcode,
  other,
  otherbox
);
  }
  return result;
}

function storeBooking(
  fname,
  lname,
  start,
  email,
  gender,
  phone,
  streetname,
  suburb,
  state,
  postcode,
  skill,
  other,
  otherbox
) {
  sessionStorage.fname = fname;
  sessionStorage.lname = lname;
  sessionStorage.start = start;
  sessionStorage.email = email;
  sessionStorage.gender = gender;
  sessionStorage.phone = phone;
  sessionStorage.streetname = streetname;
  sessionStorage.suburb = suburb;
  sessionStorage.state = state;
  sessionStorage.postcode = postcode;
  sessionStorage.skill = skill;
  sessionStorage.other = other;
  sessionStorage.otherbox = otherbox;
}

function getBooking() {
  if (sessionStorage.fname != undefined) {
    document.getElementById("confirm_fname").textContent = sessionStorage.fname;
    document.getElementById("confirm_lname").textContent = sessionStorage.lname;
    document.getElementById("confirm_email").textContent = sessionStorage.email;
    document.getElementById("confirm_gender").textContent = sessionStorage.gender;
    document.getElementById("confirm_phone").textContent = sessionStorage.phone;
    document.getElementById("confirm_start").textContent = sessionStorage.start;
    document.getElementById("confirm_streetname").textContent = sessionStorage.streetname;
    document.getElementById("confirm_suburb").textContent = sessionStorage.suburb;
    document.getElementById("confirm_state").textContent = sessionStorage.state;
    document.getElementById("confirm_postcode").textContent = sessionStorage.postcode;
    document.getElementById("confirm_skill").textContent = sessionStorage.skill;
    document.getElementById("confirm_other").textContent = sessionStorage.other;
    document.getElementById("confirm_otherbox").textContent = sessionStorage.otherbox;
    
    
    document.getElementById("a_fname").value = sessionStorage.fname;
    document.getElementById("a_lname").value = sessionStorage.lname;
    document.getElementById("a_email").value = sessionStorage.email;
    document.getElementById("a_gender").value = sessionStorage.gender;
    document.getElementById("a_phone").value = sessionStorage.phone;
    document.getElementById("a_start").value = sessionStorage.start;
    document.getElementById("a_streetname").value = sessionStorage.streetname;
    document.getElementById("a_suburb").value = sessionStorage.suburb;
    document.getElementById("a_state").value = sessionStorage.state;
    document.getElementById("a_postcode").value = sessionStorage.postcode;
    document.getElementById("a_skill").value = sessionStorage.skill;
    document.getElementById("a_other").value = sessionStorage.other;
    document.getElementById("a_otherbox").value = sessionStorage.otherbox;
  }
 }

function prefillcard()
{ 
  document.getElementById("fname").value =  sessionStorage.fname;
  document.getElementById("lname").value =  sessionStorage.lname;
  document.getElementById("email").value =  sessionStorage.email;
  document.getElementById("gender").value =  sessionStorage.gender;
  document.getElementById("phone").value =  sessionStorage.phone;
  document.getElementById("start").value =  sessionStorage.start;
  document.getElementById("streetname").value =  sessionStorage.streetname;
  document.getElementById("suburb").value =  sessionStorage.suburb;
  document.getElementById("state").value =  sessionStorage.state;
  document.getElementById("postcode").value =  sessionStorage.postcode;
  document.getElementById("skill").value =  sessionStorage.skill;
  document.getElementById("other").value =  sessionStorage.other;
  document.getElementById("otherbox").value =  sessionStorage.otherbox;
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", prefillcard);

function init() {
  var regForm = document.getElementById("regform");

  regForm.onsubmit = validate;
}


window.onload = function() {
  init();
  var date = new Date();
  var dd = date.getDate();
  var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear();

  //Add a zero if one Digit (eg: 05,09)
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = "0" + dd;
  }

  //Add a zero if one Digit (eg: 05,09)
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = "0" + mm;
  }

  var minYear = yyyy - 80; //Calculate Minimun Age (<80)
  var maxYear = yyyy - 15; //Calculate Maximum Age (>18)

  var min = minYear + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
  var max = maxYear + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;

  document.getElementById("start").setAttribute("min", min);
  document.getElementById("start").setAttribute("max", max);

};
```

```js
(function () { //Enhancement 1
    setTimeout(function () {
        history.back();
    }, 180000);
})();

function cancelBooking(){ //Enhancement 2
    window.location = "index.html";
  sessionStorage.clear();
}

function init() {
  document.getElementById("cancelpurchase").addEventListener("click", cancelBooking);
  getBooking();
}
```

I've set up a form with a submit and cancel button, with the submit button sending all the inputted data to the server and the cancel button sending the user to the homepage. For some reason, only one or the other can be there at the same time and cannot coexist. If my cancel button is activated, I can still submit to the server and cancel the form but all my validation doesn't work. The two separate snippets are in two separate external JavaScript files linked to the same HTML.

Note: no jQuery or Inline JavaScript.

Comment: Can you add the html that you used for the two buttons to your question's description ?

Comment: Please edit your question and give your html code for the buttons. Only then, I may be able to help you.

Comment: @SwapnilPrakash I've added the HTML. Both buttons are at the bottom. Thank you.

Comment: @ZouhairDre I've added the HTML. Both buttons are at the bottom. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the cancel button to submit the form to the server, or just redirect back to index.html? If the latter, then make it `type='button'` - then it won't submit the form.

Comment: @andrew Problem still persists for some reason.

Comment: try using type="reset" in your cancel button

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that both of the buttons have type "submit".

```
<input type="submit" value="Apply">
        <br>
        <br>
<input type="submit" id="cancelpurchase" value="Cancel Application"></input>
```

It causes form to be submitted (and trigger the `onsubmit` event correspondingly) - and that is default behaviour for any browser.

To resolve the issue - set `type="button"` for your cancel button.

Comment: The same problem persists for some reason? The validation still doesn't work when the JavaScript code for the cancel button is present.

Comment: Make sure you rebuilt the project or if you are editing raw html/js files make sure that you cleaned the cache properly. I believe browser simply cached the old one

Comment: I've already tried to clear the browser cache but it didn't work. I didn't include all the HTML as I believed it was useless. I'll include it (the new HTML code will be at the top of the HTML snippet). Keep in mind that those two JavaScript snippets are in two separate external JavaScript files linked to a single HTML file.

Also, I've found that the checkbox validation (top of the second snippet) works but the rest of the validation doesn't. Maybe that's where the answer can be found?